# How to instruct Datetimepicker that the time selected is of another timezone

Tags: javascript, datepicker, timezone, datetimepicker

I am using [Timepicker](http://trentrichardson.com/examples/timepicker/) jQuery plugin in order to allow the input of time in addition to date.

However, I have been struggling for some time to make it understand that the time that I actually pick is not the local time:

My users are actually picking the time that a maintenance is going to take place in Hong Kong.

So "2013/09/30, 14:00" is actually the time in Asia/Hong_Kong TimeZone.

I have been using also the [timezone-js](https://github.com/mde/timezone-js) library which is very good at manipulating and converting between timezones.

My code is this:

jQuery init:

```
jQuery(function (){
jQuery('#trouble_ticket_start, #trouble_ticket_end').datetimepicker({
  changeMonth: true,
  changeYear: true,
  dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
  showButtonPanel: true,
  gotoCurrent: true
});
```

Before anybody asks, I have installed the Olson timezone files correctly.

Now firing up the JS Console in Chrome:

```
dt = jQuery("#trouble_ticket_start").datepicker("getDate");
>> Mon Sep 30 2013 14:00:00 GMT+0200 (CEST)
```

The above is correct. However, I want my timezone to default to Hong Kong. Is it possible to do it?

I am moving on and convert that to a timezone-js object:

```
dtj = new timezoneJS.Date(dt, 'Asia/Hong_Kong');
>> timezoneJS.Date {_useCache: false, _tzInfo: Object, _day: 1, year: 2013, month: 8…}
dtj.toString();
>> "2013-09-30 20:00:00"
dtj.getTimezone();
>> "Asia/Hong_Kong"
```

This is of course correct. But how can I default my initial time pick to Hong_Kong timeZone?

Thanks in advance...

pR

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/q/15981131